# Meaning of "Guy’s heart’s gotta look like a whoopee cushion"

Tags: sentence

I don't understand the bold part. Could you help this? The background is morgue.

> Dr. Dick Miller: Internal bleeding from impact. Fatal sternal
>   fracture, eight broken ribs, ***guy’s heart’s gotta look like a
>   whoopee cushion. Whoa. This dude really axed into the fat shack.
>   Dusted. Fubar. Wipe out.***

Comment: There is nothing complicated or subtle about this sentence. Have you tried looking up the words in a dictionary? It is informal and slangy but straight-forward.

Comment: The heart might be so damaged that it looks like a blown out whoopee cushion.

Comment: @nvz a [whoopee cushion](https://www.google.ca/?q=whoopee%20cushion) is not a crushed cushion.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I'm aware, but thanks. :)

Comment: @nvz: can you please tell me why OPs talk about bold and no bold text shows in questions. I tried looking this up on this site and cannot find anything.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 - I don't think /axed into the fat shack/ is so easy to understand.

Comment: @Lambie I can see the **bold** part of the question. I don't know why you can't see it, sorry.

Comment: @nvz - Yes, I can see your **bolding** but not in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

A "whoopee cushion" is a novelty toy that produces a farting sound when the victim sits on it. It is a flat rubber sack when not inflated.  The doctor is here comparing the deceased's heart to a flattened whoopee cushion.

"Dusted" is from "done and dusted" meaning fully completed.  "Fubar" is an acronym meaning "f*'d up beyond all recognition."  "Wipeout" is a surfing term meaning to be swept off the board by a wave.  Put together, these three slang terms imply a catastrophic and terminal accident.

"Axed into the fat shack" is a bit more difficult.  It's not an idiom I know or could locate.  In context, it might be a reference to the mangled condition of the deceased's corpse (potentially exposing some of his body fat).